# Can the tf.exe vc merge /discard command be undone?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tf-cli

I am using the `tf.exe vc merge /discard` command to remove a few changesets as merge candidates, and was wondering if there was a way to undo this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the merge is checked in, you can roll back the merge for those specific files if I'm not mistaking to revert the loss of the merge ticket.

Worst case you can perform a `tf vc merge /force` on these files.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Apparently there's a difference between the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 vs VS2015. This worked with VS2012.